# Does jQuery validation work if my input element is within a label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following

```js
function setupFormValidation() {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") === "resume") {
          $("#uploadFile").addClass("error");
          error.insertAfter("#uploadFile");
        } else {
          error.insertAfter(element);
        }
      },
      unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if ($(element).attr("name") === "resume")
          $("#uploadFile").removeClass("error");
        else {
          //default behavior
          $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
          $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
        }

      }

    });
    //form validation rules
    $("#job_form").validate({
      debug: true,
      rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        confirm: {
          equalTo: "#email"
        },
        resume: {
          required: true,
          accept: 'docx|doc|odt|pdf'
        }
      },

      messages: {
        name: "Please enter your full name",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        confirm: "Emails should match",
        resume: {
          required: "need a resume",
          accept: "we only accepted documents with extension .pdf, .doc, .docx, .odt"
        }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
      }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="job_form" action="/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="job_form">
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="confirm" name="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Email Address" type="text" value="" />
  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message">
  </textarea>
  <div class="upload-info">
    <strong>Upload your resume</strong>
  </div>
  <label class="upload-btn">Browse
    <input id="resume" name="resume" type="file" />
  </label>
  <span id="uploadFile">No file selected</span>

  <button type="submit" class="send">Send Application</button>
</form>
```

However the validation function doesn't detect anything related to the file `input` named `resume`. It used to work before but don't know what happened. However if I removed the `input` tag from the `label` and put it after the `textarea` it works fine. Any pointers on how to debug this?

Comment: Did you try moving it just outside label and place it next to the label itself?

Comment: If you do that, the styling will look odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your sw and discovered that you probably are missing an include.
Only when I added the second include all works fine.

```
<script src="./jquery-validation-1.14.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-validation-1.14.0/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
```

This because the "accept" rule is defined in the additional-methods.

```js
$(function() {
            $.validator.setDefaults({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if (element.attr("name") === "resume") {
                        $("#uploadFile").addClass("error");
                        error.insertAfter("#uploadFile");
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    if ($(element).attr("name") === "resume")
                        $("#uploadFile").removeClass("error");
                    else {
                        //default behavior
                        $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
                        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
                    }

                }

            });
            //form validation rules
            $("#job_form").validate({
                debug: true,
                rules: {
                    name: "required",
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    confirm: {
                        equalTo: "#email"
                    },
                    resume: {
                        required: true,
                        accept: 'docx|doc|odt|pdf'
                    }
                },

                messages: {
                    name: "Please enter your full name",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    confirm: "Emails should match",
                    resume: {
                        required: "need a resume",
                        accept: "we only accepted documents with extension .pdf, .doc, .docx, .odt"
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }

            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="job_form" action="/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="job_form">
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="confirm" name="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Email Address" type="text"value="" />
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message">
</textarea>
    <div class="upload-info">
        <strong>Upload your resume</strong>
    </div>
    <label class="upload-btn"> Browse
        <input id="resume" name="resume" type="file" />
    </label>
    <span id="uploadFile">No file selected</span>

    <button type="submit" class="send">Send Application</button>
</form>
```

Comment: While the snippet that you posted works, it still doesn't work for me. I added the the `additional-methods` file and I also changed my version to match yours. Any ideas what would cause that?

Comment: No, because like you said, using your code (html & Js) and only adding the second include all works. So for me there is no error or the problem is in another section of your sources. Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't working because I had this line in my css `label.upload-btn input[type="file"] { display: none; }` and the validation doesn't work for hidden fields by default. I thought this only applies if you have a `hidden` attribute.